# What type of engine is mounted on the Cessna Citation Hemisphere?

Tags: jet-engine, bypass-ratio

What type of engine is mounted on the Cessna Citation Hemisphere?

[Image Source](https://cessna.com)
[image]

That does not look like a high bypass turbo jet engine.  If its not a high by pass turbo jet engine, and given a high bypass turbo jet engine is the most efficient engine, why was it not used for this particular aircraft and why was the particular engine chosen for this aircraft given its cruise speed is similar to that of aircraft that use the high bypass tubo jet engine?

Answer (score 3):

The [Cessna website](https://cessna.txtav.com/en/citation/hemisphere) mentions the engine type used (emphasis mine):

> The Citation Hemisphere will be powered by two next-generation **Safran™ Silvercrest™ engines** delivering over 12,000 pounds of thrust. The Silvercrest engines incorporate the latest advanced, field-proven technologies to offer unrivaled performance in its class in terms of direct operating cost, propulsion efficiency, reliability and environmental friendliness. These engines lower fuel consumption by up to 15 percent, reduce NOx emissions by up to 40 percent under CAEP/6 standards and half the noise footprint compared to other engines in its class.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safran_Silvercrest), this engine will have a bypass ratio of

$$5.9 \, : \, 1 $$

which would certainly count as a high-bypass turbofan engine. Also see: [What is the difference between a high bypass turbofan and a low bypass turbofan?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26709)

Comment: seems the bypass air and hot air have a singe exit at the back hence the question

Comment: @securitydude5 [This](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25774/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-mixing-the-bypass-flow-with-the-cor) question should answer that.

Comment: It's more of a not-so-high bypass turbofan compared to turbfans used in airliners.  Bypassing air trades low mass/high velocity for more mass/lower velocity (take that to the extreme and you have a turboprop) and at high altitudes where there isn't much mass to work with, it's better to go with a bit less bypass in corporate aircraft that cruise about 10000 ft higher than airliners.